# What data type does YCSB load into a database?

Tags: ycsb

I am loading data to Cassandra through YCSB using this command -

bin/ycsb load cassandra-10 -p hosts="132.67.105.254" -P workloads/workloada > workloada_res.txt

I just want what "**sort of data**" is loaded using above command. I mean a single character or a string.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to run the same command with the `basic` switch instead of the `cassandra-10` one?

From the [documentation](https://github.com/brianfrankcooper/YCSB/wiki/Running-a-Workload):

> The basic parameter tells the Client to use the dummy BasicDB layer. [...]
>   If you used BasicDB, you would see the insert statements for the database [in the terminal]. If you used a real DB interface layer, the records would be loaded into the database.

You will then notice that YCSB generates rowkeys like `user###`, with `###` < `recordcount`. The columns are named `field0` to `fieldN` with `N` = `fieldcount` - 1 and the content of each cell is a random string of `fieldlength` characters.

`recordcount` is given in `workloada` and equals 1000.

`fieldcount` defaults to 10 and `fieldlength` to 100 but you can overwrite both in you workload file or using the `-p` switch.